# How to ignore zeros when calculating correlations between columns for sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have a sparse csr matrix of size 1Million rows * 1500 columns. I want to calculate the correlation between the columns.

```
def corrcoef_csr(x, axis=0):
    '''correlation matrix, return type ndarray'''
    covx = cov_csr(x, axis=axis)
    stdx = np.sqrt(np.diag(covx))[np.newaxis,:]
    return covx/(stdx.T * stdx)

def cov_csr(x, axis=0):
    '''return covariance matrix, assumes column variable
    return type ndarray'''
    meanx = x.sum(axis=axis)/float(x.shape[axis])
    if axis == 0:
        return np.array((x.T*x)/x.shape[axis] - meanx.T*meanx)
    else:
        return np.array((x*x.T)/x.shape[axis] - meanx*meanx.T)
```

I am calculating currently correlation using corrcoef_csr(ip_matrix). But, I want to ignore the entries where both the columns are zeros while calculating the correlation between those columns.

Any idea, how could I do that?

Comment: Show us what you would do with 2 columns.  They can be dense or sparse.  It can even be iterative.  We need something more concrete than your description.

Comment: @hpaulj I want to calculate Pearson coefficient between 2 columns. So, let's say there are 1500 columns, I want to calculate Pearson coefficients between all these columns to create a 1500*1500 correlation matrix. The above code works fine. But, I think it also considers zeros in the given columns. e.g. if column A has values [0, 1, 0] and B has values [1, 0, 0]. I would like to remove 3rd row (since it has 0 in both columns) for pearson coefficient calculations. I can do that by taking two columns at a time and converting it to dense matrix and then ignoring zeros, but it runs out of memory.

Comment: Dense arrays are much better when you need to access specific columns and rows.  Sparse matrices, especially the `csr` format was designed for linear algebra tasks like matrix products and inverses.  Even `sum` is implemented as a product.

Comment: Any idea how could I achieve my task without running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy non zero to return an array with only the non-zero elements, e.g. `xnz = x[numpy.nonzero(x)]`. You need to ensure your use of shape, etc corresponds to the size of the reduced array `xnz.shape[axis]`.

You can also use masked [arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.html) or convert zeros to `nan` and use `np.nanmean` and `np.nanstd`. There is an interesting discussion of missing data in general http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/missing-data.html

Comment: In the OP question `x` is sparse.  `np.nonzero` does not work with it, though it does have its own method.  Masked arrays also don't work with it.  `covx` is dense.